# Is there a way to connect my domain with heroku using nameservers

Tags: heroku, server, dns, hosting, cpanel

I have a domain that I bought from [dataplugs](https://www.dataplugs.com/en/). They don't support CNAME configuration. They only have nameservers. In there cpanel, there is an option for **alias** domain, but it is not working instead it redirects to my heroku sub-domain. I researched about it everywhere but didn't get a proper answer. One way I find on the internet that uses a **[pointdns](https://pointhq.com/)** (a heroku plugin) but I'm not sure about that, I didn't saw any option to add nameservers. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some domain name registrar allows aname/alias to point naked/root domain, but if this is not working in your case, then you can use pointDNS.Please try to follow the below-mentioned steps

> 1. Go to APP -> settings-> under domain section add below domains
>
> - domainname.com
> - [www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com)
>
> 2. Go to resources-> add PointDNS addon,
>
> - Verify by clicking on pointDNS
> - Copy all NS records from dataplug to pointDNS
> - Update NS issued by pointDNS (dns8.pointhq.com,dns12.pointhq.com) in
>   dataplug